# Php script runs fine but doesn't create the table in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys all the elements of my php script seems to work, it connects to the database, its gets the input from a different page and saves it as a variable, i have echo'd the sql statement and run it in myphpadmin and it works but when i do it from the php script everything runs as expected except no table is created in the database.
appreciate any advice you can throw at me
thanks guys

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","odoylegaming","pwd","odoylegaminggallerydb");

if(!$con)
{
die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$Gallery_Name=$_POST['newgallery'];
if($Gallery_Name=="")
{
header("Location:Profile.php");
}
else
{
mysqli_select_db($con, "odoylegaminggallerydb");
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $Gallery_Name(User_Name VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY, Picture VARCHAR(250), Description VARCHAR(250), Date_Posted TIMESTAMP)";

$result = mysqli_query($query, $con);

if(false===$result)
{

die("table create failed: ". mysqli_error($con));
}
else
{
echo $query;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Check this query and try
`$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$Gallery_Name}(User_Name VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY, Picture VARCHAR(250), Description VARCHAR(250), Date_Posted TIMESTAMP)";`
and you making other mistake
**mysqli_query accepts 1st arugment as connection to db and 2nd as query**

Answer (score 0):

Please read the manual on `mysqli_query()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

The connection argument comes first, not second as you have it now.

By the way; you're open to a serious sql injection here. Use a prepared statement.

Creating a table from user input isn't safe at all.

Also add `exit;` after header, otherwise your code may want to continue to execute.

Comment: Yeah i have just started trying to teach myself all of this as off a few weeks ago. Security is definitely one thing that i haven't looked into that i need to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is vulnerable to sql injection please consider using prepared statements or a library like PDO to help guard against that sort of thing, that being said you are creating a dynamic table which is not a thing you can do with parameters in my example I added a few cleaners but this sort of thing isn't a safe design by its very nature. You really shouldn't be creating tables dynamically inside your application, if you need to create separate galleries rely on the relational nature of MySQL and have a Gallery table with a user_id and a User table where that ID is sourced then insert new entries using parameterized queries where if the user doesn't exist you create them and then add a gallery entry with that user's id.

#### The question

The root of your issue in this case is that you are supplying your arguments out of order for the query, your connection variable should come first. In my example I use object oriented mysqli instead of the procedural way, if you are just learning I would advise you to use classes (like mysqli) as objects even if they happen to have a procedural implementation.

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_POST['newgallery']) || empty($_POST['newgallery'])) {
    header("Location:Profile.php");
    return;
}

try {
    $galleryName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'newGallery', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // If filter fails throw error related to variable cleaning
    if (!$galleryName) {
        throw new Exception('some descriptive message');
    }

    // if you really prefer procedural: $mysql = mysqli_connect();
    $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'schema');

    // if mysqli does not instantiate, throw error
    if (!$mysqli) {
        throw new Exception($mysqli->error);
    }

    // this is still not ideal, but you can't create a table with a parameterized value.
    // the better question is why are you trying to create dynamic tables, that seems like poorly considered engineering.
    $tableName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($galleryName);
    /**
     * Procedural:
     * $tableName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $galleryName);
     * $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)
     */
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$tableName}` (User_Name VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY, Picture VARCHAR(250), Description VARCHAR(250), Date_Posted TIMESTAMP)"
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception($mysqli->error);
    }

    echo 'Table creation success.';
    return true;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e)
}
?>
```